# Is it possible to combine multiple MySQL queries in one while()?

Tags: php, mysql, deprecation-warning

```
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1); $row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))

{
    echo $row1['line'];
    echo $row1['style_no'] ;
    echo $row2['line'];
    echo $row2['style_no'] ;

}
```

Comment: Can you please make more of an effort to describe your problem properly?

Comment: ***Notice:*** There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them with `and`

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1) and $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    ...
}
```

But it would probably be better to combine the two queries into one with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi...Baemar,  Thaxx for the Advice...its fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1) && $row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    echo $row1['line'];
    echo $row1['style_no'] ;
    echo $row2['line'];
    echo $row2['style_no'] ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Efog; thax for the advice.....but according to your way...it run only second Query ($sql2) and Echo only $row2['line'] and $row2['style_no'], even other query ($sql1) have output.

Comment: Maybe $row2 have more rows then $row1? Why cannot you combain two queries in SQL?